# How to share a heavy object in Nunit between fixtures?

Tags: caching, nunit, fixture

All.
I do some integration tests with NUnit and need a long running client setup per fixture. For me it will be good to setup the client only once. This will significantly reduce overall time. i do it now with a static field in the parent fixture. Is there a better way to cache it? Probably some context, etc.

Thanks in advance, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

i've found appropriate solution - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.5.9
it will be executed only once before any fixtures and will store reference to the heavy object. any fixtures can reuse it.

Comment: Please post more details on the solution if possible, the link you posted is dead right now and relying on it brings down the quality of your answer on StackOverflow.